# MySQl Events are not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I am trying to use `EVENTS` in my project, So for testing purpose I created a `table` and created `event` for inserting data and scheduled that event for every 1min, So it has to insert data for every 1min but it is not inserting

```
CREATE TABLE event_test (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
message VARCHAR(60),
ttl DATETIME
);
```

Event:-

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS test_event_01
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO insert into event_test(message, ttl) values ('Test', NOW());
```

Mysql Version:-

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64)
```

After creating Event, I am able to see event using `show events` query

```
test    test_event_01   root@localhost  SYSTEM  RECURRING       1   MINUTE  2018-05-03 10:19:43     ENABLED 1   utf8    utf8_general_ci utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Did read the manual about MySQL Events? "This statement creates and schedules a new event. The event will not
run unless the Event Scheduler is enabled. For information about
checking Event Scheduler status and enabling it if necessary, see
Section 23.4.2, “Event Scheduler Configuration”"

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

Comment: When I run `show events` there I have seen `test_event_01` status as `enable` . It means it is already enabled?

Answer (score 0):

We need to set event scheduler globally using following query

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```